# Add plugins to a C program

Tags: c, plugins

Good morning everyone, i ll be so happy and grateful if someone could help me and give me some information about how to make a C program that we can add to it plugins, how exactly we can make plugins and add them to a C program .
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This is really far too broad. And you didn't even provide any context.

Comment: @user3386109 That is simply not true, of course there are programs with plug-ins written in C. The text editor/IDE [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) is one example off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No portably, no.

In POSIX you can use [`dlopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) and friends to implement dynamic loading of code into which you can call. You need to decide how you want to make the main program's functionality available to the plug-in, it can be a bit messy.

In Win32 the classical solution used to be [`LoadLibraryEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa), not sure if that is still considered acceptable; I don't do a lot of Windows development.

For an example of an open-source program (i.e. you can read its source and learn how it's done) see the lightweight text editor/IDE called [Geany](https://www.geany.org/).

Comment: I applaude your effort to help at least a little. But I get the impression that even for this you were already side-tracked into guess what OP is actually asking about. I feel that the definition of "plugin" (i.e. its effect and its intended use) needs clarification to support any kind of answer.

Comment: plugin like knx, Zwave, Enocean, ...

Comment: Not sure, but this might be my first accepted answer that has less than 0 score. Okay ...

Comment: well there's a first time to everything you know ;), but thank you for your effort